# add SMTP to php mail

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I have been having errors with my php mail function.  My hosting provider gave me the following information:

In order to enable SMTP authentication you would need to edit your php mail function to include:
- From address (you already have this as admin@domain.com so that should work)
- SMTP host/server: uscentral.server.com
- SMTP port: 25, 26, or 2525
- Email password: The same as you use when logging in webmail for admin@domain.com

Any ideas on how I add these?  My code for the php mail function is as follows:

```
function mail1($runTotal, $accountArray) {
        $to = $accountArray[0]['phoneNumber'] . "@vzwpix.com";
        $subject = '';
        $msg = "You have spent $" . $runTotal . " of $1,750 since the beginning of the month.";
        $msg = wordwrap($msg);
        $headers = 'From: admin@domain.com';
        if (mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers)) {
            echo $msg . " sent to " . $to;
        }
    }
```

Comment: With mail () yo can't. You need phpmailer

Comment: You can, buy adding a `-f` options to your sendmail options, but it's a much better idea to [use PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).